# MVC Role Authorization is Inconsistent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to add role authorization to certain pages in my website. I only have two roles, 'admin' and 'rep', and users can only be assigned to 1 role at a time.

The problem is, I keep getting inconsistencies in my authorization. When logging in as a user with the admin role, I have access to some pages but not to others.

--

with my admin account, I have access to this page without a problem:

**Account Management**

```
// GET: /Manage/Index
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    ViewBag.StatusMessage =
        message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
        : message == ManageMessageId.SetUsernameSuccess ? "Your username has been set."
        : message == ManageMessageId.SetUsernameUnique ? "That username is taken."
        : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
        : "";

    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var model = new ManageViewModel();
    model.UsernameModel = new SetUsernameViewModel();
    model.PasswordModel = new ChangePasswordViewModel();
    model.UsernameModel.Username = user.UserName;
    return View(model);
}
```

This one assumes I don't fulfill the role and redirects me to the login page:

**Role Management**

```
// GET: ManageRoles
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult ManageRoles()
{
    IList<RoleModel> accountsList = new List<RoleModel>();


    IdentityDbContext context = new IdentityDbContext("MavcoConnectionString");
    var allUsers = context.Users;

    foreach (var u in allUsers)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByEmail(u.Email);
        accountsList.Add(new RoleModel(user, UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id)[0]));
    }
    return View(accountsList);
}
```

Role and Account Management are both located in ManageController.

--

The other location where this a real problem is for my downloads page. The index is here:

```
// GET: Downloads
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var downloadsList = new List<DownloadModel>();
    if (db.Downloads.Any())
    {
        foreach (Download ddb in db.Downloads)
        {
            DownloadModel d = new DownloadModel(ddb);
            downloadsList.Add(d);
        }
    }

    string myId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    ViewData["role"] = UserManager.GetRoles(myId)[0];
    return View(downloadsList);
}
```

The relevant HTML is here:

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
@if ((string)ViewData["role"] == "admin")
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New File", "CreateDownload")
}
```

When I'm logged in with my admin account, the 'Add New File' link shows up. Which means I'm being recognized as an admin.

HOWEVER...I get rejected if I try to follow that link.

**DownloadsController**

```
    // GET: CreateDownload
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult CreateDownload()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying the download link from the same browser session as the other action? Have you checked with Fiddler or browser tools to make sure your authentication information is being passed to the CreateDownload action?

Comment: `I get rejected`. Does it mean you are redirected to Login Page?

Comment: @Shawn Yea, they're all in the same session. I haven't heard of Fiddler and am not familiar with browser tools. I'm still very new to authentication. Logging in is never a problem; any page with a simple [Authorize] has always worked. It's just the roles that throw a fit.

Comment: @Win Yes, sorry. It's a redirect to login, the same thing that occurs with Role Management.

Comment: Did you set any restriction on Controller class? Normally, we set Role based Authorization on Controller class. The main reason is if some developers forget to place it on Action methods, it could be a disaster.

Comment: @Win I originally had admin authorization on ManageController, but when I realized it wasn't working I removed it and added them to each action individually.

Comment: Why dont you ditch the ViewData and use `User.IsInRole("admin")`?

Comment: @stevenackley so that's a whole other monster. For some reason, that returns null. I can't use the Roles object at all because it doesn't work for me. When adding roles, I have to create it with a role manager, because calling Roles.CreateRole() throws some error about there not being enough space in my database.

Is the bad functionality of the Roles object causing all of this?